# Checking if $T_x M$ is a direct sum of the stable and unstable subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, dynamical-systems

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and $U \subset M$ a non-empty open subset and $f : U \to M$ a $C^1$ diffeomorphism. Let $x$ be a hyperbolic fixed point of $f$, i.e. no eigenvalue of $df_x$ lies on the unit circle. Consider the following subspaces
$$E^s = span \{v : v \;\text{eigenvector with eigenvalue}\; \lambda, |\lambda| < 1\}$$
$$E^u = span \{v : v \;\text{eigenvector with eigenvalue}\; \lambda, |\lambda| > 1\}.$$

I can't show if $T_x M = E^s \bigoplus E^u$ or not. Can someone give me a hint, please?

Comment: This looks like a problem in linear algebra, dynamical systems only gave the motivation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V=T_xM$. Fix a basis of $V$ and consider the matrix $A$ defined as 
$$
\sum_i A_{i, j}e_i = df_x e_j.$$ 
(This is just the matrix that represents $df_x$ with respect to the given basis $e_1, e_2\ldots e_n$). You are asking whether $V$ is spanned by the eigenspaces of the matrix $A$, which happens precisely when $A$ is *diagonalizable*.

The assumptions you gave are not enough for the diagonalizability of $A$. Indeed, $A$ can be any matrix without eigenvalues of modulus $1$. For example, $$A=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$$ is admitted by your assumptions and it is not diagonalizable.

Comment: I see that somebody downvoted this. May I ask why?