# Why the stable manifold of a point intersects the unstable manifold of another point

Tags: dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds

Let M be a smooth manifold, $f$ a diffeomorphism on M and for $p, q \in M$ consider $W^s_p$ the stable manifold in $p$ (i.e. the set of points whose forward orbit tend to the forward orbit of $p$) and $W^u_q$ the unstable manifold in $q$ (i.e. the set of points whose backward orbit tends to backward orbit of $q$).

I don't understand why $W^s_p$ intersects $ W^u_q$. Can someone explain me, please?

P.S. In my case, p is a fixed point and q a periodic point.

Comment: Do you consider a particular example? Because if $p$ and $q$ are saddle points the intersection of $W^s_p$ and $W^u_q$ is not necessarily non-empty and this is usually an additional assumption.

Comment: Yes. I consider $f$ being the hyperbolic toral automorphism on $n$-dimensional torus.

Comment: I think you should clarify your question as much as possible. The original question is rather vague and has simple, but not interesting answer. But the question in the comments is very concrete.

Comment: Actually you have the answer in this other question of yours https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2544962/checking-if-t-x-m-is-a-direct-sum-of-the-stable-and-unstable-subspaces?rq=1. Note that in that question the stable and unstable spaces are defined incorrectly.